# Show that $|z - w| \geq \big||z|-|w|\big|$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Show that $|z - w| \geq \big||z|-|w|\big|$ given $z = x + iy$ and $w = u + iv$.

So far I have,

$$|z - w| \geq \big||z|-|w|\big|$$
$$\sqrt{(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2} \geq |\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} -\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}|$$

At this point I get a little 'undone'.

I tried a few different routes, but none of them have come up with the desired result.

Comment: Do you know triangle inequality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers address your issue in a better way but I think it will be nice if a proof by your line of thought is given.

---

$$\sqrt{(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2} \geq |\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} -\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}|$$

Since both sides are $>0$,

$$(x - u)^2 + (y - v)^2 \geq x^2 + y^2 - u^2 + v^2  -2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$$

$$(x^2 + u^2 -2xu) + (y^2 + v^2 - 2yv) \geq x^2 + y^2 + u^2 + v^2  -2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$$

$$-xu - yv \geq -\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\sqrt{u^2 + v^2} -xu - yv \geq 0$$

$$\sqrt{x^2u^2 + x^2v^2 + y^2u^2 + y^2v^2} -xu - yv \geq 0$$

$$x^2u^2 + x^2v^2 + y^2u^2 + y^2v^2 \geq x^2u^2 + y^2v^2 + 2xyuv $$

$$x^2v^2 + y^2u^2  \geq  2xyuv \tag{*}$$

If you remember (*) is golden AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you cleared up my question. I came unstuck while squaring the inequality.

Comment: @Ron You are welcome :).

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you I mean $>0$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Without using the triangle inequality, we can write

$$\begin{align}
|z+w|&=\sqrt{(z+w)\overline{(z+w)}}\\\\
&=\sqrt{|z|^2+|w|^2+2\text{Re}(z\bar w)}\\\\
&=\sqrt{(|z|-|w|)^2+2\overbrace{(|z|\,|w|+2\text{Re}(z\bar w))}^{\ge 0\,\,\text{since}\,\,|\text{Re}(z)|\le |z|}}\\\\
&\ge \sqrt{(|z|-|w|)^2}\\\\
&=||z|-|w||
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Does Re means the real part? btw, I've found you in tour page.

Comment: Yes, it means the real part.

Comment: @N1ng Sometimes fancy $\Re(x)$ is also used for showing real part.

Comment: @Dr. MV: not really "without using the triangle inequality" ... since the proof of it is precisely obtained by comparing the developments of $\left| z+w\right|^2$ and of $\left(\vert z\vert+\vert w\vert\right)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Triangle Inequality, we get
$$|z|=|(z-w)+w|\leq |z-w|+|w|\tag 1$$ and $$|w|=|(w-z)+z|\leq |w-z|+|z|=|z-w|+|z|.\tag 2$$ Using $(1)$ we get
$$|z|-|w|\leq |z-w|\tag 3$$ and using $(2)$ we get $$-(|z|-|w|)\leq |z-w|,$$ that is we get
$$-|z-w|\leq |z|-|w|.\tag 4$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$, we get
$$-|z-w|\leq |z|-|w|\leq |z-w|.$$
Because $|z-w|\geq 0$, we get
$$\big||z|-|w|\big|\leq |z-w|.$$

Answer (score 1):

You probably know that $\vert a+b\vert\le\vert a\vert+\vert b\vert$ for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

Now, given $(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ :

$$\vert z\vert=\vert(z-w)+w\vert\le\vert z-w\vert+\vert w\vert$$

Hence :

$$\vert z\vert-\vert w\vert\le\vert z-w\vert$$

And by symmetry, we also have :

$$\vert w\vert-\vert z\vert\le\vert w-z\vert$$

which can be written :

$$-\left(\vert z\vert-\vert w\vert\right)\le\vert z-w\vert$$

Finally :

$$\left|\vert z\vert-\vert w\vert\right|\le\vert z-w\vert$$as desired.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\mid z-w \mid&=\sqrt{(z-w)\overline{(z-w)}}\\
&=\sqrt{(z-w)(\overline{z}-\overline{w})}\\
&=\sqrt{\mid z\mid^{2}+\mid w\mid^{2}-2\Re(z\overline{w})}\\
&=\sqrt{(\mid z\mid-\mid w\mid)^{2}+2\mid z\mid \mid w\mid-2\Re(z\overline{w})}\\
&=\sqrt{(\mid z\mid-\mid w\mid)^{2}+2\mid z\overline{w}\mid-2\Re(z\overline{w})}\\
&\geq\sqrt{(\mid z\mid-\mid w\mid)^{2}}\text{ \{since $\mid z\overline{w}\mid \geq \Re(z\overline{w})$ \}}\\
&=\bigg| \mid z\mid -\mid w\mid \bigg|
\end{align*}